# How to Show/hide a <div> based on radio checked, not clicked

Tags: javascript, forms

I am trying to show a `<div>` when a certain radio button is selected by the user. 
I found some nice code form http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/faq/show-hide-divs-based-on-radio-button-selection-in-jquery.php and I adapted it for myself like this:

With the CSS & script:

```
 <style type="text/css">
    .box{padding: 2px;display: none;margin-top: 2px;border: 0px solid #000;}
    .red{ }
    .green{  }
    .blue{ }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type="radio"]').click(function(){
        if($(this).attr("value")=="Tax representation"){
            $(".box").not(".red").hide();
            $(".red").show();
        }
        if($(this).attr("value")=="VAT recovery"){
            $(".box").not(".green").hide();
            $(".green").show();
        }
        if($(this).attr("value")=="Other"){
            $(".box").not(".blue").hide();
            $(".blue").show();
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Then I got this to remember the selection:

```
if (!empty($_REQUEST['object'])) { $object = $_REQUEST['object']; }
```

Add the radio selection in the form that remembers the selection if the form needs to be reloaded:

```
<input tabindex="1" type="radio" name="object" <?php if (isset($object) && $object=="Tax representation") echo "checked";?> value="Tax representation">Tax representation
<input tabindex="2" type="radio" name="object" <?php if (isset($object) && $object=="VAT recovery") echo "checked";?> value="VAT recovery">VAT recovery
<input tabindex="3" type="radio" name="object" <?php if (isset($object) && $object=="Other") echo "checked";?> value="Other">Other
```

Followed with the `<div>` to be shown or hidden:

```
    <div class="red box">text 1</div>
    <div class="green box">text 2</div>
    <div class="blue box">text 3</div>
```

Now my problem is that when the form is reloaded, the radio selection is memorized, but the corresponding `<div>` does not show. 
I believe there may be a way to change the script from "click" to "selected" or something like that. Would you help?

Comment: This is off-topic here but is a good fit for our sister site StackOverflow. If you flag it a moderator can migrate the question for you.

Comment: Your callback fired when radio button clicked, but when you reload page, this event not fired. You can programmatically fire event onClick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is similar to previous answers, extracting the behavior into a function so that you can run it on page load and in an event:

```
function showBoxes(value) {
  if(value=="Tax representation"){
    $(".box").not(".red").hide();
    $(".red").show();
  }
  if(value=="VAT recovery"){
    $(".box").not(".green").hide();
    $(".green").show();
  }
  if(value=="Other"){
    $(".box").not(".blue").hide();
    $(".blue").show();
  }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  showBoxes($("input[type='radio']:checked").attr("value"));
  $('input[type="radio"]').click(function(){
    showBoxes($(this).attr("value"));
  });
});
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uda982jr/)

Comment: Works great, straight  out of copy/paste, Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `change` instead of `click`

```
$('input[type="radio"]').change(function(){
```

Then, move your function to a variable and call it when the page loads.

The final code should look something like this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var updateDivs = function(){
        if($(this).attr("value")=="Tax representation"){
            $(".box").not(".red").hide();
            $(".red").show();
        }
        if($(this).attr("value")=="VAT recovery"){
            $(".box").not(".green").hide();
            $(".green").show();
        }
        if($(this).attr("value")=="Other"){
            $(".box").not(".blue").hide();
            $(".blue").show();
        }
    }
    $('input[type="radio"]').click(updateCheckbox);
    $.proxy(updateDivs, $('input[type="radio"]'))
});
```

Comment: mmm.. I did not get this one to work. Thanks anyhow! The above did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line after your `$('input[type="radio"]').click(function(){` code and inside the `document.ready` block

`$('input[type="radio"]:checked').trigger('click');`

Your current logic will work only when the radio buttons are clicked. So let's trigger the click event of the checked radio button when the page reloads. Which inturn will run your logic and toggle the divs accordingly.

Comment: It sounds right, but... does not work :-( Did I understand well? Did it like this:

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type="radio"]:checked').trigger('click');
    $('input[type="radio"]').click(function(){
        if($(this).attr("value")=="Representation fiscale"){ (etc)

Comment: I mentioned that you have to place the line below your .click event binder logic..